# How to push SQLCLR updates to your (CI) server

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, sqlclr

I'm re-using some .NET code between SQL 2005 server and WinForm clients using SQLCLR.

This code has dependencies beyond .NET 2.0 which means I have to add these assemblies on the server machine (e.g. `CREATE ASSEMBLY`).

I'm trying to do this as part of a CI build and am wondering what methods have worked best.

Answer (score 1):

Create an *.sql file with the sequence:

1. DROP FUNCTION ...
2. DROP ASSEMBLY ...
3. CREATE ASSEMBLY ...
4. CREATE FUNCTION ...

and call it with sqlcmd as part of your build.

Comment: Yep, good answer, but missing the component of how you are converting the IL into format for the `CREATE ASSEMBLY`?

Comment: The IL conversion is not necessary: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2011/01/24/deploying-clr-assembly-hangs-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx